# How to restore innodb tables without ibdata1 and *.ibd files

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, restore

By some reason these files ibdata1, ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1 were been deleted from hard drive, mysql server was restarted and of course one of the database stoped with error "db.table does not exist!". Is it possible to restore somehow these files, if there are only *.frm, db.opt files?

Thanks.

Comment: The Percona Data Recovery Tool for InnoDB is a free toolkit for recovering lost or corrupted data from InnoDB tables. For more details you can refer http://www.percona.com/software/mysql-innodb-data-recovery-tools

Comment: Yes, I've installed/compiled it already, but I have no idea how I can use it :), could you help me with that?

Comment: You are unfortunately, screwed..sorry for your loss..**flies away**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take disk image as soon as possible or mount MySQL partition read-only(if it was not on /).

Then you need to compile data recovery toolkit(install dependencies if "make" fails):

```
  make
```

Then scan the disk image with page_parser. It will find InnoDB pages and sort them per page type, per index_id.

```
  ./page_parser -f /path/to/disk.img
```

Then you need table structures (either take them from old backup or restore from .frm). You need the structure to compile constraints_parser - a tool that fetches records from InnoDB page(s).

```
  ./constraints_parser -5f pages-XXXXXX/FIL_PAGE_INDEX/0-x/
```

Save output in some file. It will also generate `LOAD DATA` to stderr to upload the dump back to MySQL.
Check the documentation on Percona's website for more details.

From my experience, 70-80%% of data should be recoverable after this kind of accident.